# Getting Started with JavaScript MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascriptmvc

I wish to learn how javascript mvc works. I know the basics of `javascript` and `jQuery`.

So i have started reading [this](http://static.javascriptmvc.com/docs/cookbook.creating.html). I am having a tough time in understanding the **How it Works** part. To be more specific I lost it from the "*`This loads CanJS's core, which includes can.Model, and uses it to create a constructor function that lets us create, retrieve, update, and delete models programmatically like:`*"

The question which came in my mind are :

1. Where are the code for create, retrieve, update, delete written ?
2. How did the model build automatically, it has title and description as attributes. But i do not remember specifying them ?
3. Are there any other resources which can be better than the link I shared ? A video tutorial helps me the most.
4. Am I missing something major ? Something I need to know before I start ?

Comment: You'll have a small application core that contains the constructors and prototypes of your model/view/controller modules. Then you write seperate modules that will use these constructors. So all your CRUD operations will probably be on your core when it comes to creating modules or on the prototype of each module. Your model will do all the data fetching/manipulating, the view will just generate html and the controller will run the show and tell the model & view when to do what.

Comment: How did the model build automatically, it has title and description as attributes. But i do not remember specifying them ?

Comment: The core will specify some properties that all models will have. When `cookbook/models/recipe.js` gets loaded, the core creates a model that all `new recipe`s will use. Title and description are things that seems to be defined in the core. Every time you create a new instance from a model, you send a name and description to the model that will be used in your instance.

Comment: are there any resources that can be helpful besides this

Comment: The internet's full with resources on mvc. But alot of it is written a bit complicated. http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvc-and-mvp-for-javascript-and-backbone-developers/ and relevant pages helped me alot, but you might have to read it all like several times to grok it. edit: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_frameworks  and https://alexatnet.com/articles/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript